I'm trying to write a WebAPI endpoint to collect OTEL telemetry exported by my application
I'm new to OTEL. I may be doing this completely wrong, based on wrong assumptions or misunderstanding of the model.
I'm writing a Telemetry prototype. My concept is that a source console application will export telemetry data to a target http endpoint which I will implement as a WebAPI application.
Here are the relevant details of the source console application:
<!-- OTEL Configuration -->
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT" value="http://localhost:58234/Telemetry" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS" value="" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TIMEOUT" value="1000" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL" value="http/protobuf" />

Some of this is repeated within code:
        m_traceProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddSource(c_Service)
            .SetResourceBuilder(
                ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                    .AddService(serviceName: c_Service, serviceVersion: c_Version))
            .AddConsoleExporter()
            .AddOtlpExporter
                (exp =>
                    {
                        exp.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:58234/Telemetry");
                        exp.ExportProcessorType = ExportProcessorType.Batch;
                        exp.BatchExportProcessorOptions = new BatchExportProcessorOptions<Activity>()
                        {
                            MaxQueueSize = 1,
                            ScheduledDelayMilliseconds = 1000,
                            ExporterTimeoutMilliseconds = 10000,
                            MaxExportBatchSize = 1,
                        };
                    }
                )
            .Build();

When I run the console application I see the output from the ConsoleExporter:

However, I've got a breakpoint set in my http target endpoint, but it's not getting hit. I've tried several tweaks, ExportProcessorType.Simple and I've inserted a ForceFlush() into the code just subsequent to the span.End() statement. No joy.
Here is the designated endpoint:
public class TelemetryController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("telemetry")]
    [Route("telemetry/v1/traces")]
    [Route("telemetry/v1/metrics")]
    [Route("telemetry/v1/logs")]
    public IHttpActionResult Submit()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;

        return Ok();
    }
}

I can confirm that this is valid, because I can hit these routes from Postman and step into the code.

But the source console application, while it is exporting telemetry information to the console, it is not posting to the designated target endpoint. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

The default is gRPC, try changes to HTTP, and be aware that it's in Protobuf format not JSON. I'd question why you'd want to receive the telemetry though, instead of an otel collector or using a purpose built backend.

Thank you! One of our developers suggested this as well. Curious, how come this is not being picked up from the specification in the config file? 

You're correct of course, regarding the eventual destination for this data. This is more of a development utility so that as we get off the ground with this we can see that we're constructing our explicit telemetry properly. I'd like to see what we're going to be sending. The console output has limited utility in this sense because the content it emits is not persistent, can't be examined after the fact.

@MartinDotNet Your suggestion worked! If you want to post this as the answer, I'll accept that to your credit. Thanks!

Look at using the Aspire Dashboard (not the full Aspire app framework) instead of developing something, you'll get off the ground quicker. In relation to the environment variable, it might be that you're overriding options so it's not taking that into account.
